# Why is spotlight shining through cube? (Blender 2.80 EEVEE render view)

Tags: light

I'm wondering why the spotlight here, if I'm seeing what's going on correctly, seems to be passing right through the cube. Thanks for any ideas.[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your Lamp properties - do you have 'Shadow' enabled or disabled?

Comment: With light selected> properties panel> object data> Shadows are enabled, but enabled or disabled here, same result as in image. Generally, with shadows enabled there, light will not pass through object, whereas with disabled shadows there, light does pass through. This is a different situation I think. I'm not really sure what I'm seeing. Thanks for any other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

For any curious about this, here's the nature of the problem and the solution
at Blender bug reports. Turns out it's not a bug, but I had thought it might be,
so to help by reporting it I thought I'd inquire there at Blender bug reports.
https://developer.blender.org/T63768